# python return / print highest number of value in a row in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, return-value

I am a beginner.

Trying to make a function that can return the highest number in a row a value in a list was picked.

Basicly I want to simulate a head or tails game, and find out how many times in a row it was for example tails.

```
import random

def simulations(runs):
    sequence = []
    in_a_row = []
    tæller = 0
    for run in range(0, int(runs)):
        my_random = random.randint(0,1)
        sequence.append(my_random)

        if my_random == 0:
            in_a_row.append(my_random)
            tæller = tæller + 1            
            print()
        elif my_random == 1:
            tæller = 0
            in_a_row = []
            print()
        print(f'{tæller}')   
        print(sequence)

# runs = input('How many simulations do you want to run ? ')
runs = 10
simulations(runs)
```

I think I am almost there. But I cant figure it out, when I run this code I first print the actual value that was picked, and then see the list that was created so far.

if for example my_random == 0 3 times in a row it will print each time it was 0 until it picks 1.

Want i want is for the code to print only the longest sequence where 0 was picked in the entire list

I know my code is spagetti, and the function is not finished, but i belive I can do that by myself. I just need some help with isolating the number of times a given value was picked in a row from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I think I was finally able to create a solution by myself.

So happy i think i spend like 5 hours trying to figure it out.

Here is my solution. I would still appriciate it a lot if someone can comment on my solution, and maybe show another more simple way of doing it :-)

```
import random

def simulations(runs):
    sequence = []
    in_a_row = []
    found_zero = 0
    all_time_high = [0]
    for run in range(int(runs)):
        my_random = random.randint(0,1)
        sequence.append(my_random)

        if my_random == 0:
            in_a_row.append(my_random)
            found_zero = found_zero + 1            
            print(f'fundet 0 ja: {found_zero} Gange')
            all_time_high.append(found_zero)
        elif my_random == 1:
            found_zero = 0
            in_a_row = []
            print()

        print(sequence)
        print(f'Higest number of times in a row zero was found: {max(all_time_high)}')

# runs = input('How many simulations do you want to run ? ')
runs = 10
simulations(runs)
```

Comment: `in_a_row` isn't used to calculate anything.  Lines mentioning it can be removed and you'll get the same result.

Comment: `all_time high` doesn't need to be a growing list.  Use an integer `all_time_high = 0` and replace `all_time_high.append(found_zero)` with `all_time_high = max(all_time_high,found_zero)` so it always equals the highest value seen so far.  Then in the final print use `{all_time_high}` without `max`.